# Rails: How to check if jsonb column is empty Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am having trouble checking when the jsonb column of my table is empty.

My column **directions** when empty has value **"{}"**

Tried the following

```
Model.where("directions != '{}'") <- brings all
Model.where("directions <@ '{}'") <- brings all
```

is there any other way that i am not aware of? Using postgresql 9.6

Comment: `Model.where("directions != '{}'")` should work, but `Model.where.not(directions: '{}')` feels more railsy (but is equivalent). If these queries return all of your data, then are you sure you have any instances with actual directions data in them?

Comment: @Frost the only syntax that worked is `Model.where.not(directions: '{}')` . To answer your questions yes i had both-case records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Model.where.not(directions: '{}')
```

Comment: `ERROR:  operator does not exist: json <> unknown`

Comment: @philpirozhkov gotta check if something changed during these 4-5 years :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Model.where.not("directions::text = ?", "{}")
```

Answer (score -3):

Try to negate query with `.not`:

```
Model.where.not("directions = '{}'")
```

Comment: I agree with Petros, this is invalid syntax as of 2017 and Rails 4.